# How to implement Grad Cam on custom model in tensorflow, Graph disconnected error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Hello I created a model through transfer learning, the model is an image classifier that classifies between 2 classes (celeba and uc_merced land use) and outputs a logit I tried to apply grad cam as seen in the keras [guide](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) with very little alterations

You can see the model summary below

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 sequential (Sequential)     (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 tf.math.truediv (TFOpLambd  (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
 a)                                                              
                                                                 
 tf.math.subtract (TFOpLamb  (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
 da)                                                             
                                                                 
 mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Func  (None, 7, 7, 1280)        2257984   
 tional)                                                         
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d (  (None, 1280)              0         
 GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                         
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 1280)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 1281      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2259265 (8.62 MB)
Trainable params: 1281 (5.00 KB)
Non-trainable params: 2257984 (8.61 MB)
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here is the code in google colab:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import tensorflow as tf
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/testUnit224E25.h5')
```

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

#model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

img_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/pics/over.png'
#img_path = '/content/over.png'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
```

Now this is the part where I implement the grad cam

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as c_map
from IPython.display import Image, display
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.applications.xception import Xception, preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import os
```

```py
IMG_SIZE = (224, 224)
last_conv_layer = "mobilenetv2_1.00_224" # I pick the last convolutional layer
```

```py
def vectorize_image(img_path, size):
    '''
    Vectorize the given image to get a numpy array
    '''
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=size)
    array = image.img_to_array(img)
    array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0) # Adding dimension to convert array into a batch of size (1,224,224,3)
    return array
```

```py
image_path = img_path
vectorized_image = preprocess_input(vectorize_image(image_path, size=IMG_SIZE))
model = loaded_model
model.layers[-1].activation = None # Removing the last layer as it is the softmax layer used for classification

preds = model.predict(vectorized_image)

for prediction in preds:
    print("predictions: ",prediction)
```

```py
def get_heatmap(vectorized_image, model, last_conv_layer, pred_index=None):
    '''
    Function to visualize grad-cam heatmaps
    '''
    gradient_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.inputs], [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer).output, model.output]
    )

    # Gradient Computations
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = gradient_model(vectorized_image)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)
    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap) # Normalize the heatmap
    return heatmap.numpy()

plt.matshow(get_heatmap(vectorized_image, model, last_conv_layer))
plt.show()
```

Running all these gets this error

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "Conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

If you need the model you can find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qJag7jc07A8qthsTznHE_Qt9C50kT0vU/view?usp=drive_link)

I really don't know what this error is and how to fix it if you have any suggestions it would really help

Thank you